# Twilio Messages are not sending in PHP

Tags: php, twilio-php

I am using twilio api for sending messages.
Following is my script.

```
$AccountSid = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$AuthToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$from = 'xxxxxxx';
$to = '+91xxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$uri = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' .$AccountSid . '/SMS/Messages';
$auth = $AccountSid . ':' . $AuthToken;

$fields = '&To='.urlencode( $to ).'&From='.urlencode($from).'&Body='. urlencode('This is my test message');


$res = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $res, CURLOPT_URL, $uri );
curl_setopt( $res, CURLOPT_POST, 3 ); 
curl_setopt( $res, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );
curl_setopt( $res, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth ); 
curl_setopt( $res, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); 
$result = curl_exec( $res );
return $result;
```

SMS are not coming to my mobile.

Is twilio works for indian mobile numbers?

Comment: @Ramya.twillo working for indian mobile numbers .you have add to  +91

Comment: I added +91 to my number

Comment: @Ramya.you can check Gowri answer because same think happend to me also.if your  Twilio account is under trail mode then you will not receive sms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You script is correct. Yes, Twilio works for indian numbers.

Is your Twilio account is under trail mode. If it's in trail mode sms are not sent for non registered(Verified) mobile numbers. You have to register your mobile number in twilio service.

From twilio console verify your testing mobile number.

Use this url to https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified verify your mobile number.

After that verified mobile number will receive sms's.

Comment: Thanks, It's working I received sms after verifing 'to' number.